# merge two bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap

I use this code for zooming and changing location of imageview. One image view is stable and one is zooming and moving by touch. I want to merge them but when the two image merged, first image is in her first location and first size before zooming. how can merge them with new size and location?

```
 //and below is the brightIt func
 public static ColorMatrixColorFilter brightIt(int fb) {
 ColorMatrix cmB = new ColorMatrix();
 cmB.set(new float[] { 
  1, 0, 0, 0, fb,
  0, 1, 0, 0, fb,
  0, 0, 1, 0, fb,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0   });

 ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
 colorMatrix.set(cmB);
//Canvas c = new Canvas(b2);
//Paint paint = new Paint();
ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
//paint.setColorFilter(f);   
return f;
 }







  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // handle touch events here
  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
  switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          savedMatrix.set(matrix);
          start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
          mode = DRAG;
          lastEvent = null;
          break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
          oldDist = spacing(event);
          if (oldDist > 10f) {
              savedMatrix.set(matrix);
              midPoint(mid, event);
              mode = ZOOM;
          }
          lastEvent = new float[4];
          lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
          lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
          lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
          lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
          d = rotation(event);
          break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
          mode = NONE;
          lastEvent = null;
          break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          if (mode == DRAG) {
              matrix.set(savedMatrix);
              float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
              float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
              matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
          } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
              float newDist = spacing(event);
              if (newDist > 10f) {
                  matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                  float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                  matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
              }
              if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                  newRot = rotation(event);
                  float r = newRot - d;
                  float[] values = new float[9];
                  matrix.getValues(values);
                  float tx = values[2];
                  float ty = values[5];
                  float sx = values[0];
                  float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                  float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                  matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
              }
          }
          break;
  }

  view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
  return true;
 }

 /**
  * Determine the space between the first two fingers
  */
 private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
  float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
  float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

 /**
 * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
 */
  private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
  float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
  float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
  point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
  }

    /**
      * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
   *
     * @param event
    * @return Degrees
     */
 private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
  double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
  double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
  double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
  return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
I used the matrix of ontouch class in mergeBitmaps class. background is an imageview that can be draged, scaled and rotated. so in line:

```
            canvas.drawBitmap(stickerBitmap, matrix, null);
```

I used the matrix of ontouch to set the bitmap in the correct location.
on imageview is stable here and only background can be drag and ... .

```
  public Bitmap mergeBitmaps() {
    Bitmap baseBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) on.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    Bitmap mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBitmap.getWidth(), baseBitmap.getHeight(), baseBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mergedBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, new Matrix(), null);



        Bitmap stickerBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) background.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        canvas.drawBitmap(stickerBitmap, matrix, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, new Matrix(), null);


    return mergedBitmap;
}
```